# How do I get rid of the Appstore's update notification?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

[image]

How can I get rid of that type of notification without actually opening the Appstore? The fact that it will stay there until I actually open it is pretty annoying.

OSX Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swipe to the right to dismiss the notification.

From [*Mac Basics: Notifications keep you informed*](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5362?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

> To dismiss an alert notification without interacting with it, use your pointer to swipe the banner to the right.

Comment: This only works for banners, not alerts.

Comment: @grgarside are you sure. Apple explicitly mentions "alert notification"

Comment: Well, I can only swipe banners — the alerts don't move…

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the automatic check for updates in System Preferences → App Store.

[image]

When it does not check for updates, it won't make notifications. :)